# How can I import python modules from outside the module's project structure without getting a ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I created a python project, using Pycharm if it matters, that looks like this:

```
outer_dir/
    outside_main.py
    module_example/
        module_main.py
        tests/
            test_1.py
            …
        level_1/
            foo_1.py
            level_2/
                foo_2.py
```

`main.py` calls functions from `foo_1.py`
`foo_1.py` calls functions from `foo_2.py`

The general use case I'm trying to emulate is a python "package" or repo called `module_example` that has been downloaded and used by `outside_main.py` at the same level as the top-level package directory.

Here's how module_main.py looks:

```py
# module_main.py

from level_1.foo_1 import foo_function_1
from level_1.level_2.foo_2 import foo_function_2


def main():
    print(foo_1())
    print(foo_2())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I can call this top level script from `test_1.py` just fine like this:

```py
# test_1.py

from module_main import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, when I try to use main() from outside the `module_example` directory, with code like this:

```py
# outside_main.py

from module_example.module_main import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/outside_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_example.module_main import main
  File "/path/to/module_example/module_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from level_1.foo_1 import foo_function_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'level_1'
```

What seems to be happening is that regardless of directory of the python script being imported, its own imports are being searched for relative to the directory from which the main script is executed.

I'm looking for a method of importing that works equally whether I'm calling `outside_main.py` or `test_1.py`, and regardless of what directory the terminal is currently pointing at.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) about how python imports work, and it basically suggests I'm out of luck, but that makes no sense to me, all I'm trying to do is emulate using someone's open source library from github, they usually have a `tests` folder within their repo, that works fine, but also I can just unzip the entire repo in my project and call import on their py files without issue. How do they do it?

Comment: Can you tell us why you *dont* want to make your code a package? This would make importing much easier for you.

Comment: @H.Doebler Your question is telling me there's something critical I don't understand about importing. I'm not against making anything a "package" as long as I can save everything in the `module_example` directory as a git repo, and move it into multiple projects without changing all the import statements each time.

Comment: Maybe it is just a typo? You did `from module_example.modules_main import main` but your file is `module_main.py`.

Comment: in your `import` statement is an `s` that is not in your modules file name.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo thank you. Fixed.

Comment: do I understand correctly, that `module_example` contains a bunch of code that you intend to use in multiple other project of yours?

Comment: @H.Doebler yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before entering the hell of `sys.path`-patching, I would suggest to wrap your code that currently lives in `module_example` into a `package_example` directory, add a `setup.py` and throw a number of `__init__.py` in.

Make `package_example` a git repo.

In every other project where you want to use `module_example.[...]`, you create a `venv` and `pip -e /path/to/package_example`.

```
outer_dir/
    outside_main.py
    package_example/
        .git/
            ...
        setup.py
        module_example/
            __init__.py
            module_main.py
            tests/
                ...
```

where `__init__.py` (one in each subdirectory that contains modules that are to be imported) can just be empty files and `setup.py` has to be filled according to the [distutils documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html).

Comment: What are the file contents of `setup.py` and `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

Use [explicit relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) (relative to the files inside the directory `module_example`). Note that the usage of [implicit relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) has already been removed in Python3

> Implicit relative imports should *never* be used and have been removed in Python 3.

**outer_dir/module_example/module_main.py**

```
# Note the "." in the beginning signifying it is located in the current folder (use ".." to go to parent folder)
from .level_1.foo_1 import foo_function_1
from .level_1.level_2.foo_2 import foo_function_2

# All the rest the same
```

### Solution 2:

Include the path to `module_example` in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (or you can also [choose](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/) to update `sys.path` directly)

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):$(pwd)/module_example
```

### Output:

Both solutions above was successful for me.

Before the fix:

```
$ python3 outside_main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "outside_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_example.module_main import main
  File "/home/nponcian/Documents/PearlPay/Program/2021_07Jul_31_StackOverflow/1/module_example/module_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from level_1.foo_1 import foo_function_1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'level_1'
```

After the fix:

```
$ python3 outside_main.py 
This is foo_function_1
This is foo_function_2
```

Comment: Have u tested this for imports in `test_1.py` when it is called as a script (`python /path/to/outer_dir/module_example/tests/test_1.py`).

Comment: I would not recommend `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`-fiddling to anyone. Thats a real pain compared to `pip -e` in a venv.